# Which sites do I need to whitelist on firewall in order for cocoapods to work?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I work on a machine which has restrictions to access the web for security reasons. I want to install cocoapods on the same machine and want it work. Which sites do I need to whitelist for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell you the a 100% bullet proof whitelist to add to your Firewall in order to use [CocoaPods](https://www.cocoapods.org).

For sure you should add:

- `*.rubygem.org` (because you install/update CocoaPods through `ruby gem`)
- `*.github.com` (To reach [`CocoaPods podspec master repo`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git) and because many projects use GitHub as their project source URI)
- `*.cocoapods.org` (in order to send stats to it, if you want)
- `*.google.com` (because google's plugins should uses it)

But other projects should set different URIs as their source repo.

So the **rule of thumb** is to add at least the above `FW` rules but, if something is still not working on your side, check the `HTTP/HTTPS requests` that are made by your machine (you should ask your IT guy for help, if you cannot do it by your own) and check out what are the ones dealing with your current pod command activity and add them to your/corporate `FW whitelist`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try them out and mark the answer as correct if it works out well.

Comment: @RohanBhale did you try?

Comment: I have informed the respective department, once they get back to me I will try this out and mark the answer.

Comment: @RohanBhale any news?

Comment: We dropped the idea of using cocoapods altogether as the department guys were not convinced. Now I have to manually compile and get the frameworks on the development machine